# Low-Level Errors using Solr and Sunspot in JRuby

Tags: ruby, solr, sinatra, jruby, sunspot

I have a simple DataMapper/Sinatra app running on JRuby as a search service. I'm getting sporadic error messages when searching (can't find particular rhyme or reason), wondering if anyone else has run into similar problems.

The errors occur randomly and are themselves inconsistent.

Examples:

```
INFO: IOError - closed stream:
 org/jruby/RubyIO.java:2616:in `sysread'
 /usr/lib/jruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:135:in `rbuf_fill'
 org/jruby/ext/Timeout.java:99:in `timeout'
 /usr/lib/jruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:134:in `rbuf_fill'
 /usr/lib/jruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:116:in `readuntil'
 /usr/lib/jruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:126:in `readline'
 /usr/lib/jruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:2026:in `read_status_line'
 /usr/lib/jruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:2015:in `read_new'
 /usr/lib/jruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:1051:in `request'
 /usr/lib/jruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:1037:in `request'
 /usr/lib/jruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:543:in `start'
 /usr/lib/jruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:1035:in `request'
 /usr/lib/jruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:772:in `get'
 /usr/lib/jruby-1.6.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rsolr-0.12.1/lib/rsolr/connection/net_http.rb:16:in `get'
 /usr/lib/jruby-1.6.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rsolr-0.12.1/lib/rsolr/connection/requestable.rb:36:in `request'
 /usr/lib/jruby-1.6.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rsolr-0.12.1/lib/rsolr/client.rb:34:in `request'
 /usr/lib/jruby-1.6.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sunspot-1.2.1/lib/sunspot/search/abstract_search.rb:35:in `execute'
 /usr/lib/jruby-1.6.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sunspot-1.2.1/lib/sunspot/session.rb:59:in `search'
 /usr/lib/jruby-1.6.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sunspot-1.2.1/lib/sunspot.rb:335:in `search'
 /var/www/search/application.rb:7:in `HEAD /search'

INFO: NoMethodError - undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass:
 /usr/lib/jruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:178:in `write0'
 /usr/lib/jruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:153:in `write'
 /usr/lib/jruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:168:in `writing'
 /usr/lib/jruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:152:in `write'
 /usr/lib/jruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:1580:in `write_header'
 /usr/lib/jruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:1535:in `exec'
 /usr/lib/jruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:1049:in `request'
 /usr/lib/jruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:772:in `get'
 /usr/lib/jruby-1.6.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rsolr-0.12.1/lib/rsolr/connection/net_http.rb:16:in `get'
 /usr/lib/jruby-1.6.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rsolr-0.12.1/lib/rsolr/connection/requestable.rb:36:in `request'
 /usr/lib/jruby-1.6.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rsolr-0.12.1/lib/rsolr/client.rb:34:in `request'
 /usr/lib/jruby-1.6.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sunspot-1.2.1/lib/sunspot/search/abstract_search.rb:35:in `execute'
 /usr/lib/jruby-1.6.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sunspot-1.2.1/lib/sunspot/session.rb:59:in `search'
 /usr/lib/jruby-1.6.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sunspot-1.2.1/lib/sunspot.rb:335:in `search'
 /var/www/search/application.rb:7:in `HEAD /search'

INFO: IOError - stream closed:
 org/jruby/RubyIO.java:1978:in `close'
 /usr/lib/jruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:70:in `close'
 /usr/lib/jruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:1059:in `request'
 /usr/lib/jruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:772:in `get'
 /usr/lib/jruby-1.6.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rsolr-0.12.1/lib/rsolr/connection/net_http.rb:16:in `get'
 /usr/lib/jruby-1.6.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rsolr-0.12.1/lib/rsolr/connection/requestable.rb:36:in `request'
 /usr/lib/jruby-1.6.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rsolr-0.12.1/lib/rsolr/client.rb:34:in `request'
 /usr/lib/jruby-1.6.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sunspot-1.2.1/lib/sunspot/search/abstract_search.rb:35:in `execute'
 /usr/lib/jruby-1.6.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sunspot-1.2.1/lib/sunspot/session.rb:59:in `search'
 /usr/lib/jruby-1.6.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sunspot-1.2.1/lib/sunspot.rb:335:in `search'
 /var/www/search/application.rb:7:in `HEAD /search'
```

The errors seem to be a problem with something underneath Sunspot (RSolr or JRuby maybe?), but I'm at a bit of a loss as I can't find a way to consistently reproduce the problem. I've tried slaughtering the Solr installation with requests to see if it is a problem with Solr/Tomcat, but I've yet to catch Solr/Tomcat dropping the ball.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was threading. By default, Sunspot's session object isn't thread-safe. In Sunspot::Rails, it uses a thread-safe object by default, but since this is Sinatra, you have to do this manually, like so:

```
Sunspot.session = Sunspot::SessionProxy::ThreadLocalSessionProxy.new(Sunspot.config)
```